How to add delay to my terminal?
I like the experience that I get from using the terminal on a remote device where there is a visible lag between what I type and what happens on screen, because it forces me to trust the actions I'm taking. Sometimes I'd like to train my fingers a bit like this, and replicate this sort of lag on my local setup.
I use GNU screen for most of my work, and thought that this should be somehow possible. Glancing at the manual, I only see an option to set baud rate when starting screen on a tty, but I'm unable to completely grasp it and figure out how to modify the baud rate on a running screen session.
Does anyone know how to set and modify such a delay/baud rate on an open session, with screen or otherwise?
Thanks.

The answer - and explanation - comes from How to throttle bandwidth of SSH connection but I don't think it's a strict duplicate.
I started by considering a 150baud teletype (15 characters per second), but this timed out, taking too long for the ssh command to establish its credentials and set up the connection, and anyway on consideration the transport speed would need to be far higher to carry an effective load of 15cps:
ssh -o ProxyCommand='pv -qL 15 | nc %h %p | pv -qL 15' localhost; echo BACK

(I should point out that the echo BACK is simply to flag when the ssh localhost command has completed. It's not particularly relevant for day-to-day use, but very convenient when testing. I'll omit it from here on.)
Reading more about pv, which I usually use as a visual display of data transferred, I remembered that it's possible to control an existing instance. So we can run the initial ssh at full speed and then experiment with reducing the bandwidth permitted through the two instances of pv:
ssh -o ProxyCommand='pv -qP p1 | nc %h %p | pv -qP p2' localhost

The PIDs are written to the files p1 and p2 respectively.
p1=$(cat p1) p2=$(cat p2)
rm -f p1 p2

We can now apply restrictions to these processes, either symmetrically or asymmetrically depending on the effect required. (Remember these are limiters at the protocol level, not the throughput you yourself experience.)
for p in "$p1" "$p2"; do pv -R "$p" -L 1K; done     # 1KB/s ≈ 8Kb/s

for p in "$p1" "$p2"; do pv -R "$p" -L 150; done    # 150B/s ≈ 1.2Kb/s

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to slow things down far enough, so I looked instead at cstream. Here we're using a buffer of one byte and an output speed of 150 characters per second:
man cstream | head -n20 | cstream -b 1 -t 150

And applying that to ssh localhost we get this:
ssh -o ProxyCommand='cstream -b 1 -t -100 | nc %h %p | cstream -b 1 -t -100' localhost

Note that it will take up to a minute to establish the initial connection!
Unfortunately, it's still blocky, but I think that cstream is probably the way to go and I may update this answer as I get alternative approaches

An incredible idea that might just work! Let me try to get the ssh proxying work with https://github.com/rom1v/delay and a custom wrapper to make it adjustable at runtime.
